# Is onclick embedded JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, semantics

This may be a subjective question. If so please close it.

Does `onclick` count as embedded JavaScript?

Or is it just usually the method called that’s actually the JavaScript part?

Comment: Simple yes or no will suffice if its that simple

Comment: I’m not exactly clear what you mean by “embedded JavaScript”.

Comment: Are there multiple types of embedded? What I understand embedded to be is javascript thats been hard coded into html.

Comment: sure. In that case, the HTML `onclick` attribute is indeed embedded JavaScript (assuming it has some JavaScript in it), because a) the value of the attribute is JavaScript, so you’ve got some JavaScript in your HTML, and b) the association between the HTML element’s `onclick` event and the JavaScript you want to call is defined in (and thus hardcoded into) the HTML.

Comment: This question is not about embedded programming - see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "hardcoded into HTML"? Do you mean JavaScript code that is directly included in a web page's source, instead of included in an external JavaScript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure what you’re asking, but I’ll have a go anyway.

The `onclick` attribute that you can add to HTML elements (i.e. `<a onclick="">`) is HTML. However, its value is JavaScript that gets run when the user clicks on the element. That JavaScript (along with the association between that JavaScript and the HTML element’s `click` event) is indeed embedded in the HTML page, meaning you have to change your HTML page to change the JavaScript (or remove the association).

To avoid embedding JavaScript into your HTML page, you can instead add a handler function to the `onclick` DOM property of an element via JavaScript:

1. Add a JavaScript file to your page, via the `<script src="">` tag.
2. In that file, set some code to run on page load (or when the DOM is ready, which is a whole other topic in itself).
3. Have that code add an `onclick` handler function to an HTML element.

E.g. if your HTML looked like this

```
<a id="needs_onclick">I need an onclick handler</a>
```

Then you could add an `onclick` handler to the link like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("needs_onclick").onclick = function(){
        alert("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

This approach would not be described as “embedded JavaScript”, as it uses the `onclick` DOM property, not the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) functions called "Event Handlers." These are commands that work
>   directly with existing HTML commands. They work so closely in fact,
>   **they work by being embedded right into the HTML** command itself.

The source: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470771/Advanced-JavaScript-for-Web-Developers-onClick-and-onMouseOver.htm

From mighty Google. Took me about 15 seconds to find it.

Comment: You’re citing an article called “Advanced JavaScript for Web Developers: onClick and onMouseOver”?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - I know what you mean :) I'm citing to answer in more credible way than "yes". Also moving away from using embedded handlers is a different topic...

Comment: @Paul That comment could have probably used a :) after it! :)